# Need help on Power BI - Stacked Column Chart

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am a beginner in Power BI, I need your help with somthing on Stacked Column chart.

I want to show some result by quarter (on the X axis), and for Y axis I am using a measure. I have a matrix on the same page, what I want to achieve is that when I select an item on the Matrix (it is a profit and loss statement), it will automatically adjust the chart.

For example, below you can seee that when I select "Material Costs Parts", it automatically updated the Line chart, the results are good, however and the Stack column chart, it is not working, because it shows the total amount of everything (which is meaning less), and ONLY Highlight Material costs parts, is there a way that the Stacked column chart shows only "Material costs Part" or any other thing depending my selection?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YfIc.png)

I tried several things, but it did not work.